# Add map elements to list with a loop

Tags: list, loops, grails, groovy

I am trying to populate a list with maps created from objects in a query/findAllBy... I always end up with list of maps identical to the last map in the loop.

I have set break points and stepped through the method and found that 1) the data returned from the query is correct, 2) as I step through the loop the data is inserted into the map(s) correctly, 3) the failure comes when inserting the map into the list. All the methods I've used to insert elements into a list (.add, .push, <<, list[(i)] = map, etc) end up overwriting all the previous elements in the list.

Please help. I don't know why this is happening. Hopefully this is an easy one for someone out there.

```
def shiftRecords = Shift.findAllByUserAndStartTimeBetween( userInstance, startDate, endDate )
ArrayList allShifts = new ArrayList()
LinkedHashMap thisShift = new LinkedHashMap()
def size = shiftRecords.size()

for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    thisShift["id"] = shiftRecords[(i)].id
    thisShift["user"] = shiftRecords[(i)].user
    thisShift["startTime"] = shiftRecords[(i)].startTime
    thisShift["posCode"] = shiftRecords[(i)].posCode
    thisShift["deptCode"] = shiftRecords[(i)].deptCode
    thisShift["billingIDX"] = shiftRecords[(i)].billingIDX

    Position thisPos = Position.findByPositionCode( thisShift.posCode )
    thisShift["posTitle"] = thisPos.shortTitle
    thisShift["deptTitle"] = thisPos.departmentTitle

    allShifts.add( (i), thisShift )
}
```

I need the results of allShifts to be a list of maps with the selected data pulled from the Shift query results. I've tried using shiftRecords.each and eachWithIndex. The problem happens with any type of loop at the point where thisShift map is inserted into allShifts. It doesnt just insert one instance of the map, but replaces all list elements with the current thisShift map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def shiftRecords = Shift.findAllByUserAndStartTimeBetween( 
                               userInstance, startDate, endDate )
ArrayList allShifts = new ArrayList()
def size = shiftRecords.size()

for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    LinkedHashMap thisShift = new LinkedHashMap()
    thisShift["id"] = shiftRecords[(i)].id
    thisShift["user"] = shiftRecords[(i)].user
    thisShift["startTime"] = shiftRecords[(i)].startTime
    thisShift["posCode"] = shiftRecords[(i)].posCode
    thisShift["deptCode"] = shiftRecords[(i)].deptCode
    thisShift["billingIDX"] = shiftRecords[(i)].billingIDX

    Position thisPos = Position.findByPositionCode( thisShift.posCode )
    thisShift["posTitle"] = thisPos.shortTitle
    thisShift["deptTitle"] = thisPos.departmentTitle

    allShifts << thisShift
}
```

You need to create a new map each time you iterate over `shiftRecords`. Although, the above code can be overly simplified in groovy as below:

```
def shiftRecords = Shift.findAllByUserAndStartTimeBetween( 
                               userInstance, startDate, endDate )
def allShifts = []

shiftRecords.each{
    def thisShift = [:]
    thisShift.id = it.id
    thisShift.user = it.user
    thisShift.startTime = it.startTime
    thisShift.posCode = it.posCode
    thisShift.deptCode = it.deptCode
    thisShift.billingIDX = it.billingIDX

    Position thisPos = Position.findByPositionCode( thisShift.posCode )
    thisShift.posTitle = thisPos.shortTitle
    thisShift.deptTitle = thisPos.departmentTitle

    allShifts << thisShift
}
```

Comment: *ahem* could be groovier still (though we have to take care not to be "too groovy")

Comment: @tim_yates Rightly said, I like baby steps plus pointing out the mistake in the approach. OP: "Can we simplify your solution more?" ME: "Yes off course look at the other answer ;)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's so simple I'm embarrassed that I spent so long pulling my hair out over it. I'm new to Groovy and Grails and sometimes over complicate things.

Comment: @CheddarMonkey As you said you are new to Groovy and Grails. You need to know how the accepted answer works instead of just using it. Explore how `collect` works. I would have taken more time to give you the same answer (or similar) instead of pointing out your mistake. But I preferred the later. :)

Comment: @CheddarMonkey Never demanded to accept my answer. Tim's answer will be best approach in your case anyway. :)

Comment: I changed it because your answer more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def shiftRecords = Shift.findAllByUserAndStartTimeBetween( userInstance, startDate, endDate )
def allShifts = shiftRecords.collect { it ->
    def pos = Position.findByPositionCode( it.posCode )
    [ id         : it.id,
      user       : it.user,
      startTime  : it.startTime,
      posCode    : it.posCode,
      deptCode   : it.deptCode,
      billingIDX : it.billingIDX,
      posTitle   : pos.shortTitle,
      deptTitle  : pos.departmentTitle ]
}
```

Comment: LOL. Simplified my solution as well. :)

Comment: Thanks for adding more GROOVE to the answer. I need all the advice I can get. Excellent answers from you and @dmahapatro.